# Is it possible to get file content in workflow using rest API?

Tags: 2013, workflow, office-365, designer-workflow

My workflow is 2013 and implemented in Office 365:

my header:

```
Accept: application/octet-stream
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
binaryStringResponseBody: true
```

url call(rest api):

```
https://<site>/_api/Web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('<site relative>/SitePages/Home.aspx')/$value
```

Note: I have created a dictionary for header and for output of ResponseContent.

```
then Call url HTTP web service with request(ResponseContent to dictionaryresponse...) // here failed call
```

When start workflow on item from list, throw error and workflow status show as suspend.

error details:

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unable to deserialize HTTP response content. Expected ContentType : 'application/json', 'text/plain' or 'text/html', Received ContentType : 'application/octet-stream'.

Do you have some idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi! any further info on how did u solve it?

Comment: No friend, I have stop here. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can't read content of file using Designer. It is in error detail, no octet-stream.
Build some backend service which will do it for you and will send it back to you in JSON.